# Parity: with 'warp' sync enabled by default, is there still any advantage in using fast pruning?

Tags: blockchain, parity, synchronization, fast-sync, warp-sync

From [Parity Ethereum Documentation](https://wiki.parity.io/Warp-Sync):

> Warp Sync is an extension to the Ethereum Wire protocol, which involves sending snapshots over the network to get the full state at a given block extremely quickly, and then filling in the blocks between the genesis and the snapshot in the background.

When I run `parity --help` for Parity v1.11.4, the bullet about `warp` says:

```
--warp
    Does nothing; warp sync is enabled by default.
```

That said, is there any advantage left in setting `pruning=fast` or `pruning=light`?

To my understanding, their purpose is to allow for a fast (but incomplete) sync.

But then, as mentioned above, `warp` seems to do that already.

So when exactly should I be using `pruning` to anything other than `archive`?

Thank you!